# After deleting android database getReadableDatabase() won't create a new database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I deleted the android database by executing rm /data/data/app/databases/database. After I removed it I tried running the app again and it thows an exception because the tables have not been created. The exception I get is E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service wificontroller.WifiControllerService: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:

I create the tables in

```
public class DataStore extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String TAG = "Database";
private static final String DatabaseName = "Database";
private static final String NICKNAME_TABLE_NAME = "nicknames";
private static final String SCAN_TABLE_NAME = "scans";
private static final int Version = 2;

private static final String NICKNAME_TABLE_CREATE = "Query I cant show"

private static final String SCAN_TABLE_CREATE = "Query I cant show"

public DataStore(Context context) {
    super(context, DatabaseName , null, Version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating database");

    try {
        db.execSQL(NICKNAME_TABLE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(SCAN_TABLE_CREATE);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not create database", e);
        Log.e(TAG, "Query 1: " + NICKNAME_TABLE_CREATE);
        Log.e(TAG, "Query 2: " + SCAN_TABLE_CREATE);
    }

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TAG, "On Upgrade called");
}
public String[] getScanColumns(){
    return new String[]{"accessPoints", "clients", "status","timeOfStartScan", "packetsFound"};
}
public String getDatabaseName(){
    return DatabaseName;
}
public String getScanTableName(){
    return SCAN_TABLE_NAME;
}
```

and the Method that is calling the database is

```
SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT QUERY", null); //THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS THE EXCEPTION

try {
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();

        Log.w(Tag, "Packets found on last scan = " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("packetsFound")));

        Log.i(Tag, "Successfully loaded database scan");
     } else {
        Log.w(Tag, "Could not retrieve scan from database");
     }
 }
 catch (Exception e){
    Log.w(Tag, "Could not retrieve scan data from database probably because it doesn't exist");
}
finally {
        mCursor.close();
}
```

I have verified that neither On Create or On Upgrade are getting called. I am sorry I cant post the queries they are propietry however I know they compile correctly because this has been working for a long time.

I have tried reinstalling the app and deleting all user data and nothing has worked. Any thoughts on why I would all of a sudden I can't query my database anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case other people run into this issue too. Mine originally failed because the database didnt know the database changed and I needed to increase the version, like said above, but I had a very similar problem when my on create failed before it tried to execute all the queries. One of the queries was bad and the first time I executed it it failed but every time after that It didn't retry to call on Create. In short if Oncreate fails once then you have to completly remove the app from the phone and try again.

Comment: Or just don't catch exceptions in `onCreate()` to prevent a broken database from being created.

Comment: Thats what I should have done in the first place. It leads to interesting behavior though so I figured I would try to help others if the came to they same place.

Comment: > In short if Oncreate fails once then you have to completly remove the
> app from the phone and try again.    

this is not a proper solution.

what if we want to give update and that update we delete the database and try to create once again. so there are error. And we can not tell user to remove app from phone and install it again!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to increse Version.

try

```
private static final int Version = 3;
```

Comment: This will cause on Upgrade to get called but why isnt on Create getting called. I need it to create the new database too.

Comment: You can: 
1. call Create function from Upgrade 
or 
2. delete application from Settings -> Application Manage and install app again.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I didnt relize though that when you delete the database it wont call on Create again. Do you have any explination for this?